# Cannot find module 'lodash' with _Layout.cshtml

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angular, lodash

I am working on Angular2 ASP.NET Core Application, and I need use lodash in one of the components.ts files. I am new to ng2 and wondering what I am doing wrong here. Please look the code and see if you see something.

The error reported:
Cannot find module 'lodash'.

Here is what I have:

### Package.json

```
{
  "name": "asp.net",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "lodash": "4.13.1",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  }
}
```

### gulp.js

```
gulp.task('moveToLibs', function (done) {
    gulp.src([
      ...
      'node_modules/lodash/lodash.js',
      ...
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/lib/'));

    gulp.src([
      'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/lib/css'));
});
```

### _Layout.cshtml

```
<script src="~/lib/lodash.js"></script>
<script>
            System.config({
                packages: {
                    app: {
                        format: 'register',
                        defaultExtension: 'js'
                    }
                },
                map: {
                    lodash: '../wwwroot/lib/lodash.js'
                }
            });
            System.import('app/boot')
                  .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
```

I am not sure what how to point to correct location here.

file structure is like this:

```
/wwwroot/lib/lodash.js
/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml
/gulp.js
/package.json
```

I am try to import the dash library like this: import * as _ from 'lodash' in
/wwwroot/app/components/some-view.component.ts